# Passport.js in Express 4.11.1, it does not write into the session.passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm encountering a little problem when using passport.js with express 4.11.1

Below is my app.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {

    if(username == '1' && password == '1') {
        var user = {username: 'test',id: 123,firstName: 'test'};
        return done(null, user);
    } else {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username or password'});
    }
}
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
    var user = {
        username: 'test',
        id: 123,
        firstName: 'test'
    };
   done(null, user);
});

module.exports = passport;
```

Then I modified my app.js, adding the middleware

```
var passport = require('./auth');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

At last, I defined in the router:

```
var passport = require('../auth');

router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {title: 'Login', message: ''});
});
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local',
        {
            successRedirect: '/user2',
            failureRedirect: '/login'
        }));
router.get('/user2', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.passport);
    if(req.session.passport.user === undefined) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        res.render('user2', {title: 'Welcome!', user: req.user});
    }
});
```

Now the problem that I found is that I can successfully login, however when I try to print out req.session.passport, I found the passport object in session is {}. I guess maybe it's because the passport.serializeUser function doesn't really work, but when I try printing out the user object passed to the passport.serializeUser function, it has values. Can someone help me look into this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except this part:

```
app.use(session({
   secret: 'secret',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: { secure: true }   <<<<<<<<<<
}));
```

[docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie) say that you should use secure cookies when you are using https, so excluding this field should fix your problem.

> secure boolean marks the cookie to be used with HTTPS only.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion. seems still not working... I' m wondering, when the function passport.serializeUser runs, it should write the user object into  session.passport, is it right?

Comment: Sorry mate, I think you are right! I tried in my office computer and it works. I'll try my home computer again later today. Thanks a lot!